# What exactly is a "persisted private key"?

Tags: rsa

I'm trying to use Microsoft's Crypto API to do some RSA.  On Windows Vista and above, my code runs without problem.

```
CryptAcquireContext(&m_hCryptProv, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);
```

Unfortunately, on the two Windows XP machines that I have tried, I get error code NTE_BAD_KEYSET (0x80090016).

A little bit of googling found this article on Microsoft Support.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238187

It mentions a CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT flag that can be passed if "you are not using a persisted private key that is stored in a key container".  When does "persisted private key" mean in this context?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "persistent", right?

Comment: The exact quote from MS Support says "persisted".  I can see how "persistent" would be interchangable in this context.

Comment: "Persisted" mean stored for reuse. For example, if you are verifying a signature you only need to have temporary access to the public key; when the signature is verified (or fails to verify) the key can be destroyed. The error indicates that the default key container is already used.

Comment: By using CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT I was able to make the error go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, my best guess is that a persisted private key is one that is put into a key store.  I do not use the key store, and I don't know why, but XP required CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT and Vista+ do not.